# MySQL change row as column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-workbench

here i have a result query, there's `service_id` 50 show twice because have two `servenginer_enginer_id` but if `service_id` show twice, i want to make as comma so `servenginer_enginer_id` is `51,53` how to do that ?

HERE is the screenshot of my table-

[image]

*sorry for my bad english

Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: if you select `service.*` then your question doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT() function to conactenate servenginer_enginer_id by ',' and group by other columns.

You can share your query, so that i can prepare it for you.

Comment: https://ibb.co/gfwbbK i was tried but just show me one row any solution ?

Comment: You need to do group by also, on "servenginer_enginer_id, service_id, service_status_id, service_customer_id, service_code, service_ref_number, service_title" these columns.

Comment: example query please ?

Comment: here it is ::: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`profile`.profile_first_name,' ',`profile`.profile_last_name)) AS servenginer_fullname,service_enginer.servenginer_enginer_id,service.*

from service 

JOIN service_enginer 
  on service.service_id = service_enginer.servenginer_service_id 
LEFT JOIN `profile` 
  ON `profile`.profile_user_id = service_enginer.servenginer_enginer_id`

Comment: ok solved, dude ^_^ thank you , u're right just need group by but can u tell me why ?

Comment: SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(service_enginer.servenginer_enginer_id) AS servenginer_fullname, service.service_id
from 
 service JOIN service_enginer 
 on service.service_id = service_enginer.servenginer_service_id 
 LEFT JOIN profile 
 ON profile.profile_user_id = service_enginer.servenginer_enginer_id
 group by service.service_id;

Comment: Thank you ^_^ , it's solved , now can you tell me why it's need GROUP BY ?

Comment: We need to use Group By statement, Becuase you are combining two or more service id in one row.
It is fine, What about other rows? We are not taking care of them. So it will throw error.
For solving that issue, we group by other column and using group_concat function on service_id.

Note: group_concat is a group by function. It is working like group by.

Comment: ooh, Thank you so much, now i got it , could we talk on other social media ? here i can't chat you cause my repuration is 5